# Custom tag-value format

Tags: php, regex, tags, format

I would like to do something like this:

```
<my_tag_name>
text..
any_text
</my_tag_name>
```

but the problem appears what if the user puts the content like this:

```
<my_tag_name>
text..
any_text
</my_tag_name>
</my_tag_name>
```

So I replaced < with <'

```
function content($string, $tagname)
{
 $pattern = "/<$tagname>([\w\W]*?)<\/$tagname>/";
 $preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
 return str_replace("<'", "<", $matches[1]);
}

function replace($string)
{
  return str_replace("<", "<'", $string);  
}
```

The goal is to have custom tags and any kind of text as a content. Is this correct approach? I tried it and it works. But then again I remembered the same principle is in html but there you can't put let's say < div> my content < div> < /div>.

I also wanted to have like this:

```
tag: reserved_64_characters
tag2: reserved_64_characters
```

How are these things implemented in XML? Is there also some escaping/replacing.
I would like to do that any content can be inserted I mean any characters(also < tag_name >..).

On http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Notes on CDATA sections:

A CDATA section cannot contain the string "]]>"

Comment: One of the best posts ever: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

In essence: Do not use regex for grammars!

Comment: +1 to "don't use regex for grammars"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape your user input with [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`CDATA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) which is exactly what you need if I understand your question right (which I doubt, unfortunately).

```
<my_tag_name>
<![CDATA[text..
any_text
</my_tag_name>]]>
</my_tag_name>
```

so

```
text..
any_text
</my_tag_name>
```

is value of `my_tag_name` now

Comment: What if user inserts text..]]> as content. Still needs to be replaces some way.

Answer (score 0):

you could use php's htmlentities() or strip_tags() to parse/scrub the user input ...

Comment: I applies only to html tags, but here I have my own tags, there could be <water>, <bla> ... or you mean just the concept og htmlentities()